# Why is a:hover and href links not working in my unordered css list?

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, href

Ok so for some reason my href links and a:hover css function aren't working. Thanks!

Also the id "mobNav" is for my mobile navigation so it shouldn't be interfering with my problem.

### Code Snippet:

```css
nav#topTab {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav#topTab ul {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

nav#topTab ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
}

nav#topTab ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
  margin: 0 15% 0 3%;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah';
}

nav#topTab ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #3a7999;
}
```

```html
<nav id="topTab">
  <a href="#" id="mobNav"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.org/" title="morning delight">morning delight</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.org/" title="yesterday">yesterday's leftovers</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.org/" title="accelaaaa">accela-meme</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: "Not working" in what way? The snippet in the question seems to work fine.

Comment: The nav blocks aren't linking to anything and the hover properties aren't being applied when I roll my mouse over them. Hmmm it might be something else then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the nav tag is expected to contain header elements. I changed the html to this:

```
<nav id="topTab">
        <a href="#" id="mobNav"></a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="http://www.example.org/" title="morning delight">morning delight</a></li>
              <li><a href="wwww.google.com" title="yesterday">yesterday's leftovers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="accelaaaa">accela-meme</a></li>
          </ul>

  <div>
    <img id="navRight" src = "forwardarrow.png" alt="forwards">
    <img id="navLeft" src = "backarrow.png" alt="backwards">
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>
    <b href="http://localhost:8000/home.html" title="Home">MemeSlutz</b></h1> 
    <h2>Dank Rank</h2>
  </div>

</nav>
```

And included the header in the nav, which for some reason the hover function and href worked.